# How to use auto generated code in Maven project

Tags: maven

We've a requirement where we need to auto generate the code and use it in another project. 
I'm using following code for autogenerating the code. But doing a "maven package" only generates sources and it doesn't give any errors in the log. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>exec-one</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.xx.yy.zzz.aa.bb.Autgen</mainClass>
                        <arguments>                             
                            <argument>-o</argument>
                            <argument>${srcOutputDir}/${packageDir}</argument>
                        </arguments>

                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin> 
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 1):

First i would suggest to generate the code in a different phase like **generate-sources** and next you have to tell the compiler plugin to compile that generated code as well. Take a look at the [build-help-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) for this purpose.

Comment: Ok, I digged down to 'AutoGen' logic and found that it is executing 'System.exit' due to some unavoidable reasons. This is causing the build to end abruptly. Is there any way around to this?

Comment: Around a System.exit No way..Check way it fails.

Comment: Seems like I've to configure dependent builds in Teamcity. First build would generate the sources and the next build would compile/package those sources.